# Shell command to format numbers inside filenames

Tags: bash, shell

I have a folder containing the following files:

```
trackingData-00-1.data, trackingData-00-2.data, ..., trackingData-00-2345.data
```

And I would like to rename them by formatting numbers with 4 digits

```
trackingData-00-0001.data, trackingData-00-0002.data, ..., trackingData-00-2345.data
```

How can I achieve that with a bash shell command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A pure `bash` solution:

```
for f in trackingData-00-*.data; do
    [[ $f =~ trackingData-00-([0-9]+).data ]]
    mv "$f" $(printf "trackingData-00-%04d.data" ${BASH_REMATCH[1]})
done
```

A regular expression extracts the number to pad and stores it in the `BASH_REMATCH` array. Then `printf` is used to create the new file name, with the number reinserted and padded with zeros.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `printf`'s options in awk to print four digits:

```
echo 3 | awk '{printf ("%04i", $1)}'
0003
echo 33 | awk '{printf ("%04i", $1)}'
0033
```

So it could be:

```
for file in trackingData*
do
  num=$(awk -F[.-] '{printf ("%04i", $3)}' <<< "$file")
  mv $file trackingData-00-$num.data
done
```

This uses `awk` with both field separators: either `.` or `-`. Then, it takes the 3rd block based on them and formats its value with the `%04i` flag (almost equivalent to `%d` as seen in [The GNU Awk User’s Guide #5.5.2 Format-Control Letters](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Control-Letters)).

Answer (score 2):

dirty but working hack:

```
for i in $(seq 2345); do
    mv trackingData-00-$i.data trackingData-00-`printf %04d $i`.data;
done
```

Comment: what if some files in the sequence are missing ?

Comment: So, you just got a warning 'No such file'. Loop don't breaks on it.

Comment: You can add `if [[ -f trackingData-00-$i.data ]]` before the `mv`

Answer (score 1):

first of all, I assume that there is no spaces in your file name. then

```
ls/find...| awk -F'-|\\.' '{o=$0;$3=sprintf("%04d",$3);$4=".data";gsub(/-\./,".");print "mv "o" "$0}' OFS='-'
```

will print the `mv ...` command. to execute them, just pipe the output to `sh` like

```
ls...|awk ..|sh
```

the core is the awk part, test it a bit:

```
kent$  echo "trackingData-00-1.data
trackingData-00-2.data"|awk -F'-|\\.' '{o=$0;$3=sprintf("%04d",$3);$4=".data";gsub(/-\./,".");print "mv "o" "$0}' OFS='-'                                                   
mv trackingData-00-1.data trackingData-00-0001.data
mv trackingData-00-2.data trackingData-00-0002.data
```